# gimp: resize and "unsharp mask" via script

Tags: shell, scale, gimp

I need to do the same operations for more than 60 files:

- scale image
- unsharpen mask

Is it possible to execute this from a script possibly passing the scale value ? I'm on Ubuntu if this could influence the answer.

`edit:`
What I need to do is to resize some Android icons from *64x64* to *96x96* (as far, maybe other resolutions too).
But these icons have already been blurred so, just increasing the size, I don't get a nice result.
I've seen that if I resize to 96x96 and apply the "*Unsharp Mask*" filter with the default values (*Radius*: `5,0` - *Amount*: `0,50` - *Threshold*: `0`),
I get an acceptable result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you are on Ubuntu, you likely already have ImageMagick installed - `convert`, `identify` and `mogrify` commands, amongst others.

So, make a copy of your data and try something like this on a copy:

```
mogrify -resize 640x480 -unsharp 6x3+1+0 *.jpg
```

or maybe this

```
mogrify -resize 1024x768 -sharpen 0x1.0 *.tif
```

to resize all JPEGs to 640x480 max and sharpen them, and in the second case to resize and sharpen a bunch of TIFFs.

If you specify your GIMP parameters I can probably make closer suggestions.

Comment: I thought I had to use some gimp's `script-fu` for this, but with `ImageMagick` it's easier and faster, thanks a lot.
I get a similar result with the `mogrify -resize 96x96 -sharpen 0x1.0 *.png` that you suggested. If after the new info I wrote, you can suggest me some other tricks, they're welcome.
Otherwise I accept the answer as it is, the result is good enough for me.

Comment: Excellent! Glad it works for you. Extra tips? There is an excellent article on unsharp mask parameters here... http://redskiesatnight.com/2005/04/06/sharpening-using-image-magick/

Comment: Another tip... you can add `-path /path/to/output/directory` to the `mogrify` command to get it to output the converted images to a new output directory rather than clobbering the input files.

Comment: OK, perfect, thanks again. You saved me some hours of work :)